# Does Apache and Tomcat support gMSA

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat

I wonder if Apache and Tomcat support gMSA as "log on as" account for their corresponding Windows service.

In latest Tomcat's documentation, there is only mention of "Domain User" but as gMSA is quite specific...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not something for Apache or Tomcat to support. "Log on as" isn't handled by the service; it's handled centrally by the Windows service manager – if a gMSA is used then the OS will retrieve the gMSA credentials and perform the logon, and the service already runs as the specified user from the first instruction.